# Tkinter - Canvas Text not centering

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

Hope you are doing great. I'm back with a other problem. So I have a Text on canvas and the problem is its not centering. I'm using this code -

```py
joke_text = canvas.create_text(
    0.0,
    0.0,
    anchor="w",
    justify='center',
    text=main.joke,
    fill="#000000",
    font=("Roboto Condensed", 39 * -1),

)
```

But it's not centering, its is always in the left
[image]

Please help, sorry for bad English and Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you expect it is in the center when you use (0.0, 0.0)? Also I can only see lower half of the text using your code since you used `anchor='w'`.

Comment: The `justify` option of a Canvas text object object only specifies how *multiple lines of text* are positioned relative to each other - it is completely irrelevant with a single line of text.  You need to use `anchor='center'`, combined with coordinates that are actually in the center of the Canvas rather than in a corner.

Answer (score 1):

The `justify` option specifies what happens to multiline text. You only have a single line of text. It will be displayed to the right of the coordinate you've given. Since you have it a coordinate of 0,0 it will appear in the upper-left corner of the canvas.

If you want the text centered, you need to give a coordinate that is the center of the canvas, and you need to set anchor to "c" (center).

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(width=400, height=200, background="white")
canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

canvas.create_text(200, 100, anchor="c", text="Hello, world", fill="#000000")

root.mainloop()
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Hello! Sorry for not including this in the question— Even though I have only one line of text, its length depends(random text). So the coordinates won't be the center every time. Do you know a solution for this? Thanks.

Comment: @JKR: I don't understand your comment. If you give coordinates that are the center of the widget, it doesn't matter how long the line of text is, it will still be centered.